# Use 'foreach' in script

Tags: php, foreach, echo

I'm trying to write a script that list all the image URL from an specific URL. I used `foreach` in order to scan several pages, but I think os not working well.

This is my code:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$array = array($page, $page2);

$page = "https://www.dllo.dev";
$page2 = "https://www.dllo2.dev";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($array);

    $images = array(); 
    foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
           $images[] = $element->src; 
    } 
    reset($images);
    echo "URL $array:<br /><br />";
    foreach ($images as $out) {
        $url = "$base$out";
        echo "$url,&nbsp";
    }
```

It's partially working, but only with the first URL (`$page`)... Any idea?

:D

Comment: $array = array($page, $page2) defined berefore $page and $page? Huh

Comment: Apart from what @RagenDazs noticed, judging by the not-so-detailed [simplehtmldom docs](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm), `load_file` can't take an array as a parameter.